# Angular.js - testing number of children in element directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got a simple `ui-spinner element` directive.

```
.directive("uiSpinner", function () {    // If a size attribute with value large
    return {                             // is present, the spinner will be
        restrict: "E",                   // relatively large.
        scope: {
            spin: "@",
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // NB: scope.size is not linked to the controller scope.
            // Because of the compilation process, it will only
            // detect static *inline* attributes. This should be
            // fine, because this attribute is static in practice.
            scope.size = "";
            if (attrs.size && attrs.size === "large") {
                scope.size = "large-";
            }

            scope.$watch('spin', function () {
                if (scope.spin === "true") {
                    element.find("#spinner").addClass(scope.size + "spin");
                } else {
                    element.find("#spinner").removeClass(scope.size + "spin");
                }
            });
        },
        template: "<div id='spinner'><div></div>&nbsp;</div>"
    };
})
```

In the test setup, I'm trying to verify that it has precisely one child.

```
describe('uiSpinner', function () {

    describe('template', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            directiveTemplate = "<ui-spinner spin='{{is_spinning}}'>" +
                                '</ui-spinner>';
            compiledEl = $compile(directiveTemplate)($scope);
        });

        iit("is comprised of a single element", function () {
            expect(compiledEl.find("*").length).toBe(2);
        });

    });

...
```

I tried testing this before with `compiledEl.children().length`, but it always returns 1. I've also tried wrapping compiledEl in `$` or `angular.element`, and still the same results. Basically, why do I need to use the obtuse `.find("*")` instead of using `.children()` to select the children of my directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `compiledEl.children()` it's always returning 1 because the only child is `<div id='spinner'></div>`.

If what you're looking for is the number of children of the `#spinner` div, you need to do `compiledEl.children().eq(0).children().length` or `compiledEl.find('#spinner').children().length`.

Comment: You're correct. I see this is really a jQuery question. `.children()` only travels one level down the DOM tree. I think `.find()` is the correct implementation for my purposes then, since I want to search recursively.

Comment: Yep! Glad I could help. I've spent countless hours in my career banging my head off the keyboard trying to figure out little things like this. console.log() is your friend. :-)

Comment: Alas, in this case it was not. :-( Or rather it was, but difficult to make use of, at least for me.